# CSS styling in parent class so that one child has 25% width of parent and another child has 75%

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Assuming that the parent has width 100%, it is wanted to make child 1 with width 25%, child 2 with width 75%.

Those two children are some custom components that cannot have their own class so the changes must be done in the parent class.

What I've tried:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent:first-child {
  width: 25%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

This one makes both of them having 25% of the parent in total.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.parent > div:first-child {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  background: #ddd;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

By setting [the `flex-basis` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) on both child elements, you can make them take up the full width of the container.

The other option would be to set the `flex-basis` of the first child, and tell the second child to grow to fill the remaining space.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.parent > div:first-child {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  background: #ddd;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

[CSS Flexible Box Layout - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)
[A Complete Guide to Flexbox - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css grid

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
}

.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to change strategy entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo-selector is faulty. It's looking for an element with class `parent` *which is* a first child. You want `.parent :first-child`, which is a descendant selector.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.parent :first-child {
  width: 25%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.parent :last-child {
  flex: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the selectors to target the child elements properly, something like :

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.parent div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
  <div> child1 </div>
  <div> child2 </div>
 </div>
```